# GLSL Porting from v110 to v150?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm attempting to port shaders from `#version 110` to `150`. I'm aware that when moving from `110` to `150` the global `gl_` properties are deprecated and therefore all those properties will have to be specified manually in the shader. Then the specified properties have to be set through C++ via calls to OpenGL through `glGetAttribLocation`.

I'm a little unsure how to handle things such as `gl_MultiTexCoord0` and `gl_TexCoord`.

Here of just one of the shaders I'm attempting to port from `#version 110` to `150`:

```
//  blinn_phong.glsl
[vert]

#version 110

varying vec3 normal;

void main()
{
    normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);

    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;    
}

[frag]

#version 110

uniform sampler2D colorMap;
uniform float materialAlpha;

varying vec3 normal;

void main()
{   
    vec3 n = normalize(normal);

    float nDotL = max(0.0, dot(n, gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz));
    float nDotH = max(0.0, dot(normal, vec3(gl_LightSource[0].halfVector)));
    float power = (nDotL == 0.0) ? 0.0 : pow(nDotH, gl_FrontMaterial.shininess);

    vec4 ambient = gl_FrontLightProduct[0].ambient;
    vec4 diffuse = gl_FrontLightProduct[0].diffuse * nDotL;
    vec4 specular = gl_FrontLightProduct[0].specular * power;
    vec4 color = gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor + ambient + diffuse + specular;

    gl_FragColor = color * texture2D(colorMap, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    gl_FragColor.a = materialAlpha;
}
```

Can anyone provide some good resources to help with porting between these versions?

Comment: Is there some reason you're not switching to GLSL 4+?

Comment: You can also make a call to `glBindAttribLocation (...)` prior to linking if you want the vertex attributes to map to a specific location, rather than relying on the GLSL implementation to assign them. You will need to do this for fragment shader outputs as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to setup your own uniforms, attributes, varyings and fragment shader outputs. The code will become similar to:

```
[vert]

#version 150 core

uniform mat3 in_NormalMatrix;
uniform mat4 in_ModelViewProjectionMatrix;

in vec3 in_Normal;
in vec4 in_Vertex;
in vec2 in_MultiTexCoord;

out vec3 normal;
out vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    normal = normalize(in_NormalMatrix * in_Normal);

    gl_Position = in_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * in_Vertex;
    texcoord = in_MultiTexCoord;    
}

[frag]

#version 150

uniform sampler2D colorMap;
uniform float materialAlpha;

struct sLightSource
{
   vec3 position;
   vec3 halfVector;
   ...
}

uniform sLightSource u_LightSource;

in vec3 normal;
in vec2 texcoord;

out vec4 out_FragColor;

void main()
{   
    vec3 n = normalize(normal);

    float nDotL = max(0.0, dot(n, u_LightSource.position.xyz));
    float nDotH = max(0.0, dot(normal, vec3(u_LightSource.halfVector)));
    ...
    out_FragColor = color * texture(colorMap, texcoord);
    out_FragColor.a = materialAlpha;
}
```

P.S. This [book](https://www.packtpub.com/android-ndk-game-development-cookbook/book) has an entire chapter dedicated to this kind of transformations between different GLSL shader versions.